# Program crashes when I try to add contents of a class to on array

Tags: java

I am trying to add a class to an array and I get **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException** in my `addAstronaut` class.

```
package gov.nasa.spacevehicles;

import gov.nasa.personnel.Astronaut;

public class SpaceStation {

//private members
   private String name;
   private double stationWeight;
   private double altitude;

private Object[] Astronauts;
private int totalAstronauts;

//overloaded constructor
public SpaceStation(String name, double weight) {
   int altitude = 0;
   int totalAstronauts = 0; 
}

//method
public void addAstronaut(String name, double height, double weight) {
     Astronauts[0] = new Astronaut(); // Exception in thread
     Astronauts[1] = new Astronaut();
     Astronauts[2] = new Astronaut();

    
     stationWeight = stationWeight + weight;  
 }
```

Comment: Because`Astronauts` array is not initialized. That's why it is null.

Comment: Think of it this way; `Astronauts[0]` accesses the first element of the array that the `Astronauts` variable references.  But `Astronauts` doesn't reference any array yet; you left it blank.  So the compiler throws an exception because your code doesn't mean anything; you're asking the compiler to do an impossible task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the `Astronauts` array. Try something like:

```
Astronauts = new Object[10];
```

in the constructor for `SpaceStation`, take the size of the array as an input to that constructor, or use an `ArrayList` for variable size lists.